# SQL Server 2012 : sa is disabled previously, due to password policy sql user is also locked

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

1. Due to the auditor recommendation, I disabled the `sa` user for SQL Server
2. New `sql` user with full privileges was created
3. Unfortunately password was expired and user in application attempt with multiple failures that locked the admin users (password policy)

Now, I am stuck with:

- `sa` - diabled
- `sql` user - locked out

I only have a local Windows user in SQL Server which does not have right to modify the `sa` or `sql` user

Thank God we have a physical cluster and we shifted but what should I do for the problem:

1. fully reinstall
2. install only SQL Server Management Studio
3. any good fast trick

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/49767/1186

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me before and thankfully it is easy to solve when you have local admin access to the physical server.  Basically you need to start the service in single user mode, connect with windows auth and either change the password or create a temporary account with sysadmin.

Step by step instructions:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Going into a new environment, sometimes I find instances where no one knows the passwords. Once I am local admin on the server I use the following process.

Here are the commands I use to gain access. The first is for a default instance, the second is for a named instance.

You can create a batch file, I call mine unlocksql.bat and put the contents in the batch file and run it on the server you are locked out of.

Default Instance:

```
net stop mssqlserver 
net start mssqlserver /mSQLCMD 
sqlcmd -Q "if not exists(select * from sys.server_principals where name='BUILTIN\administrators') CREATE LOGIN [BUILTIN\administrators] FROM WINDOWS;EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'BUILTIN\administrators', @rolename = N'sysadmin'" 
net stop mssqlserver 
net start mssqlserver 
sqlcmd -Q "if exists( select * from fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER') where permission_name = 'CONTROL SERVER') print 'You are a sysadmin.'"
```

Named Instance:

```
net stop mssql$sqlexpress 
net start mssql$sqlexpress /mSQLCMD 
sqlcmd -S (local)\sqlexpress -Q "if not exists(select * from sys.server_principals where name='BUILTIN\administrators') CREATE LOGIN [BUILTIN\administrators] FROM WINDOWS;EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'BUILTIN\administrators', @rolename = N'sysadmin'" 
net stop mssql$sqlexpress
net start mssql$sqlexpress
sqlcmd -S (local)\sqlexpress -Q "if exists( select * from fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER') where permission_name = 'CONTROL SERVER') print 'You are a sysadmin.'"
```